# Cloud Functions for Firebase: write to database on fileupload

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function (modified version of [generateThumbnail](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/generate-thumbnail) sample function). I want to create thumbnail, but I also want to get image width and height, and update size value in the database.

To break up this problem:

1. I need to get snapshot of current database
2. Navigate to `/projects` of database
3. Find correct key using filename (project.src == fileName)
4. Get size of image (done)
5. Update `project.size` to new value

I did some research, but I only found the `functions.database.DeltaSnapshot` interface, that is given, when you listen on `functions.database().ref().onwrite(snapshot => {})`

projects.json:

```
[{
    "name": "lolipop",
    "src": "lolipop.jpg",
    "size": ""
},{
    "name": "cookie",
    "src": "cookie.jpg",
    "size": ""
}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Database interaction can be done using the [firebase-admin](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start) package. Check out [this sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/authenticated-json-api/functions/index.js#L27) to see how a function not triggered by a database write accesses the database.

Accessing child nodes by the value of one of their keys in Firebase is a bit clunky, more on that at the end.

For each concern:

1 & 2: create a reference to the projects key in your DB

3: Find the project you're looking for by its `src` key

5: [Update](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-update) the project

```
// create reference
const projectsRef = admin.database().ref('projects');

// create query
const srcProjectQuery = projectsRef.orderByChild('src').equalTo(fileName);

// read objects that fit the query
return srcPojectQuery.once('value').then(snapshot => {
    const updates = {};

    snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
        updates[`${childSnapshot.key}/size`] = fileSize;
    });

    return projectsRef.update(updates);
});
```

---

Since it looks like you're treating the `src` values as unique, a lot of headache can be avoided by using the `src` as the key for each project object. This would simplify things to:

```
const projectsRef = admin.database().ref(`projects/${src}`);
projectsRef.update({'size': fileSize});
```

Comment: `srcProjectRef.update('size': fileSize)` have `:` instead of `,`. But More than that, i just got `srcProjectRef.update is not a function` error. Should I post some parts of my function?

Comment: After thinking about this some more, it is more convoluted than I originally posted. See edited post for new details.

Comment: Replace 'val' with 'value'. But it throws error anyway `this.submissionsRef` is undefined

Comment: I ended up going with the src as key method, but I would like to solve this question anyway, for future reference and for others.

Comment: Sorry, copy paste error from trying this on my own. Changed submissionsRef to projectsRef